# How to vote for a heading in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, voting

I have thousands of headings in org-mode agenda files and use this structure for a long time. I want to set up org-mode so that it has a voting system. I press a hotkey, org-mode adds +1 to a heading and then I can filter the headings by the number of votes.

---

Upd. I have to clarify the question. I can see how this can be done:

```
* heading
  :PROPERTIES:
  :VOTES:    5
  :END:
```

1) property drawers are searchable http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html, so I can use the comparison operators for filtering, e.g. `VOTES>4`.

2) I can use the propertу API http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-property-API.html for increasing and decreasing the counter.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: Er, no, you didn't. We still don't know with what you need help.

Comment: Org-mode has many features. If somebody has already created something like "voting system in org-mode" he may help me.

Comment: I suggest you just make your voting system a `tag` -- something like `:1:`  There is already a facility to insert tags with hot keys, and of course, `org-mode` has various searching options -- `org-tags-view`; `org-search-view`; `org-agenda-list`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the ability to count votes. I think I have to use `:PROPERTIES:` with integer value of `:VOTES:` for example.

Comment: And the property drawers are searchable too :) http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Comment: Yes, and I found http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-property-API.html - it will allow increase and decrease the counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution. I add + to a speed command in org-mode. You could also bind this to some key.

```
(defun plusone ()
  "Increase the VOTES property in an org-heading by one. Create
the property if needed."
  (interactive)
  (org-entry-put
   (point)
   "VOTES"
   (format "%s" (+ 1 (string-to-number
              (or
               (org-entry-get (point) "VOTES")
               "0"))))))

(add-to-list 'org-speed-commands-user '("+" . (plusone)))
```